Colocation questions / IDRAC and provisioning server
So a bunch of OS Clean servers are to be hosted in colocation (first time for our team, we used to rent bare metals).
The servers all come with iDRAC (iDRAC8 Enterprise License) and we are asked to get our own IP (DC can do byoip).
The question, will the data center usually provide some way to use iDRAC to allow us control the machines?
And what is a common practice to raise a provisioning server (non windows) for os installations?

Depends entirely on the colo what services are standard, what they will do as extra service and what you’re willing to pay for. Renting several complete racks usually allows you more freedom to (also) create your own network layouts (With the colo provider providing fibers or copper between your racks (or not) for your own switches or they provide a managed network ) compared to renting only a couple of U units in a random shared rack. Describe your wishes and expectations and talk to the colo (which you should have done before signing up) rather than asking random internet people.

I wouldn’t want my out-of-band managent interfaces connected directly to the public internet and would like a separate management network that our admins can VPN into for example, but other may have different wishes and recommendations

I imagine you could always set up your own router in an extra 1U, give it one of your IP addresses, and use it as a VPN gateway into the iDRAC ports or the iDRAC vlan?

@HBruijn first thing in getting some basic info is to ask for support any where possible.

@u1686_grawity thank you for the hint. In a local datacenter (as we can drive there I did not count it) we could get iDRAC access over a VPN they provided and that has been extremely helpful (beside the DC staff installing OS). I just have not seen any colocation providers advertise a VPN or internal network advertised, but I can see setting a router ourselves as a solution
